# Narrow indexed type by passing keys and associated values types to generic

Tags: typescript

### Differences from similar question

Unfortunately, the great answers to question [Pass implicit keys and values type relationship to TypeScript generic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65303532/4818123) does not cover the problem in current question: in `generateInputsAccessObject`, the target function of that question, we don't not use the subtype-dependent properties.

In fact, the above question has been solved without passing the implicit keys and values type relationship to TypeScript generic, which is the heading, but I suppose now we can't avoid it anymore.

### Target

Create the `EntitySpecification`, the generic type of `ProductSpecification` such as:

1. `properties`'s type must be **non-indexed**. It mean that TypeScript compiler must know what `ID` and `price` are exists, but other keys - does not exist.
2. `properties` must be iteratable (`Object.entires("ProductSpecification.properties")` must work).
3. `ID` and `price` could have different type, but when we call `EntitySpecification.properties.ID` or `EntitySpecification.properties.price`, TypeScript compiler must know which type.

```js
export type Product = {
  ID: string;
  price: number;
};

const ProductSpecification: EntitySpecification<keyof Product> = {
  name: "Product",
  properties: {
    ID: {
      type: DataTypes.string,
      emptyStringIsAllowed: false
    },
    price: {
      type: DataTypes.number,
      numberSet: NumbersSets.nonNegativeInteger
    }
  }
};
```

Here:

```
export enum DataTypes {
  number = "NUMBER",
  string = "STRING"
}


export enum NumbersSets {
  naturalNumber = "NATURAL_NUMBER",
  nonNegativeInteger = "NON_NEGATIVE_INTEGER",
  negativeInteger = "NEGATIVE_INTEGER",
  negativeIntegerOrZero = "NEGATIVE_INTEGER_OR_ZERO",
  anyInteger = "ANY_INTEGER",
  positiveDecimalFraction = "POSITIVE_DECIMAL_FRACTION",
  negativeDecimalFraction = "NEGATIVE_DECIMAL_FRACTION",
  decimalFractionOfAnySign = "DECIMAL_FRACTION_OF_ANY_SIGN",
  anyRealNumber = "ANY_REAL_NUMBER"
}

export type StringSpecification = {
  readonly type: DataTypes.string;
  readonly emptyStringIsAllowed: boolean;
};

export type NumberSpecification = {
  readonly type: DataTypes.number;
  readonly numberSet: NumbersSets;
};
```

Off course, the `EntitySpecification` does no know at advance the keys, however the keys count could be arbitrary large (not 2 as in current `ProductSpecification`).

### Best of me for now

Below solution satisfies to first two targets:

```
export type EntitySpecification<Keys extends string> = {
  readonly name: string;
  readonly properties: { [key in Keys]: StringSpecification | NumberSpecification };
};
```

Here the conflict situation, the consequence of violation of third condition:

```js
type StringValidationRules = {
  emptyStringIsAllowed: boolean;
};

const ID_ValidationRules: StringValidationRules = {
  emptyStringIsAllowed: ProductSpecification__EXPERIMENTAL.properties.ID.emptyStringIsAllowed;
}
```

Because TypeScript does not know that `ID` has `StringSpecification` type, we have below error:

```
TS2339: Property 'emptyStringIsAllowed' does not exist on type 'StringSpecification | NumberSpecification'.   Property 'emptyStringIsAllowed' does not exist on type 'NumberSpecification'.
```

Comment: I think [this](https://tsplay.dev/nWPVZN) might work for you, where you pass in the entire `Product` type and not just `keyof Product`.  If that looks good, I'll write up an answer.  Otherwise, let me know what else you need and I'll see if I can address it.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz Thank you for the solution! It's completely good; please write the answer to win this bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `EntitySpecification` is only mapping the property *key types* of an object type, whereas you need to map the corresponding *value types* also.  In this case, it would be best if you pass the entire object type in and not just its keys.  You can then map the property types via some mapping structure, while continuing to map the keys as you are doing now.

Here's one way to represent the necessary mapping structure:

```
type DataMapping =
    { type: number, specification: NumberSpecification }
    | { type: string, specification: StringSpecification }
```

Note that I don't plan to use an actual *value* of type `DataMapping` anywhere; it's just a type definition that the compiler will be able to use to connect a property type to a specification interface.

Now `EntitySpecification` can be defined as follows:

```
type EntitySpecification<T extends Record<keyof T, DataMapping["type"]>> = {
    readonly name: string;
    readonly properties: { [K in keyof T]: Extract<DataMapping, { type: T[K] }>['specification'] };
};
```

Note that I am [constraining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` to be an object type whose property types are mentioned in the `type` property of `DataMapping`.  This will allow `Product` whose property types are only `number` and `string`, but would disallow something like `{oops: boolean}` because `boolean` does not (currently) have a corresponding specification.

The `properties` property is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) in which the keys `K` are the same as the keys of `T` (as you were doing before) and whose values are translated from the corresponding property type from `T`, namely `T[K]`.

The specific property mapping is `Extract<DataMapping, {type: T[K]}>['specification']`, using the [`Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to select the member of the `DataMapping` union whose `type` property is `T[K]`, and then returning the `specification` property from that member.

---

Let's see how it works on `Product`:

```
type Product = {
    ID: string;
    price: number;
};

type ProductSpecification = EntitySpecification<Product>;
/* type ProductSpecification = {
    readonly name: string;
    readonly properties: {
        ID: StringSpecification;
        price: NumberSpecification;
    };
} */
```

That's what you wanted, I think.  If you have a value `p` of type `ProductSpecification`, then `p.properties.ID` must be of type `StringSpecification`, and `p.properties.price` must be of type `NumberSpecification`.  Hooray!

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOBZOYwEsB2BzKBeAKCmKgG8pRIAuKTAVwFsAjCAJwBooBnSAY3QBm6XgnQB7TDQByjFqwDKfQcNESoAXyIkAPmQrgINLsFZZsnHhH5CRwcZKjyTZxVeW37GggQgAPMGKswPqQUACimHagrtYqdhIAPAAqUH7AEJgAJlxQAEpWgZkJANYQIGICUEmc8IgoaGYA2gBElBDNALoAfF34ZFrErBBwmRIANiC0cAyG3M44ANwDUEMj45NgrGKQQegQXDTkjQDSUFhQpeWVSR00Yb4mcLzACbXIqBg4nORtNEknHQ0XUaAHJLLEPBIQYD1EtYd4-AEgql6AxYAg4EkDDlSMtUXI+s0pABVJAAITCuWa7GWxlMOEJ8iSuQAklIAOLNAiaHz+QLBNqOebYGLuVSYPq4kgrYajTATEKzN5YyBcAB0dLMS2lqzlCogDDA0WFLK4AEExmMxAB3CCZGhMMRiMbDTBwpa8pECgxQGTMNiimziyXLXXrRU0ZXYtX4tjakhh+WTWMKCDAaSyNhceRprjuhF85EZRi+zOsbO5-rSzAIOisOBjP0EvBQIlmpLE3JmgAyAH0SeTKdS8RIpBBsKIAG4QFmRcdsQlSADyUn7YXZ7ZZADUwr22Ul10OadXx1OZ3PsAuW0T15ud3upAf2Ue8ae7NPZ+lL6wl6wAFpsGIi63kk267vuh65L2S5QX+lJLsO0pwJgICfvOrCEmaUgAJoPk+L7SgEXDoO+EAwG4DANgAYvWzyeNeAAKS7yCyoH3jAYQAMIskgPa9lRXacaBK6ISQmBvug07kfwlFjDRTzxBK15SCBYG9hx3G8X2AlmkJLIiceJCZBR1G0YpS4CGaKHyOg2BKa2Gk8XxOl6Su0FUb2WG4Sx7JSKJxDISA+QNk2V6tl5va5GEfEDhSVLct4AD0yUpaliUFl6ipQAxWyZHQzwhtKLIwEYwrxsQmzCLMKb5gQgo5WIeXPIGcT0eEkQkSALWQpgCQNU1wBdEsiUAFRZf1+XAN1wYtlKCayuGNYzKV9LYOVMprEmUCbNsbB2PshzLEVJVCqt02KethGmLwsyhQoShBhdyzwuoUAjelBC8BIxjZblk3nfYdwddED2tYkE3PL0s14tMszNBDwD+dtWw7PtBxVtKJDFYdmO4xG6KICq+wasKhl4yQBpGl1JrmpaNp2jQAgNlwEBHSQ6icGzFXXbMc3k8QvwE5i0YpmT-Mpjm6alv65aS+qmCjhJH4XmwXNeNKmjwnVPpOKtW4NugmTirkdAujk0PSpTxqraaFpWra9pQI6zqurVX2YD9xW9vrYyG8bpsHadZg+37ikm2bhUU4a1tmLbdMOzQCMAxIao7ajezqsVapW9TNu0-bdoJQQQA)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I checked the solution and I little bit complicate this example, adding the support for `object` type. To avoid the asking of duplicate question, may I ask you to explain what means `type MODULE.DataTypes' is not assignable to type 'never'` in `category: { type: DataTypes.fixedKeyAndValuePairsObject }`? I don't understand why TypeScript expecting the `never` in this position. [Link to code sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qljhm), because links of TypeScript playground is too long.

Comment: Your object's property type is no longer an exact match for the specification type, but something narrower; you will need a more sophisticated union-member-selector instead of just `Extract` to deal with a case like this; possibly [this one](https://tsplay.dev/RwR3QN)?

Comment: It works! Thank you very must for the solution again!